# Efficiently evaluating a recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I came across with an interesting puzzle on my previous interview.
You need to implement a function which would fit the following conditions:

```
m, n - positive integer numbers > 0
F(m, n) = F(m-1, n-1) + F(m, n-1)
F(1, n) = 1
F(m, 1) = 1
```

Obviously you can write the recursive implementation:

```
int F(int m, int n)
{
    if(m == 1) return 1;
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    return F(m-1, n-1) + F(m, n-1);
}
```

But for input data equals one billion it will run very long time because it will get 2^1000000000 iterations :)
Does anybody have any ideas how to optimize this solution?

Comment: Write an iterative function instead?

Comment: that is a fibonacci sequence if i am not mistaken.

Comment: A way to visualize this function intuitively would be to ask, if there is a grid of squares with m squares across and n squares down and you start at the top left square, how many possible paths are there to the bottom right square?  (Each path is a sequence of 0 or more steps one square to the right or one square down).

Comment: Use dynamic programming ans store all already calculated values of F(m, n) in a 2d matrix. This way you avoid to calculate anything again which was already previously calculated.

Comment: You can use Matrix exponentiation method !

Comment: @Steveo, not exactly true, `n` always increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
function F(m, n)
    v = 1
    s = 1
    k = 1
    while k < m do
        v = v * (n-k) / k
        s = s + v
        k = k + 1
    end
    return s
end
```

Comment: I just arrived at the same method! Will you explain how you derived it?

Comment: @MartinR - I have noticed that it is equal to sum of part of row inside Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Well done! I cheated by looking up some values in OEIS and finding http://oeis.org/A004070 :-)

Comment: Thank you! Your decision is pretty nice. However, I am looking for a faster implementation which probably uses the cache. Do you have any ideas how to solve this puzzle using the cache for storing precalculated results for this function? I mean that if I just store all result for all values it will take 2^64 elements in the data structure. Maybe there is some more efficent way for storing only some parts of results?

Comment: @OlegIgnatov - All dynamic-programming-like methods will probably have quadratic time complexity, but you are limited to linear solutions only.  Кэш тут нафиг не нужен.

Comment: It works only for m<n. If m>=n we can calculate the result this way: 2^(n-1). It's interesting, is not it? :) I also read a lot of information about Pascal's triangle and tried to understand how to derive this formula: v=v*(n-k)/k but in vain. It's clear for me that it works but I have absolutely no idea how you discovered it. Could you explain please how this formula is related with Pascal's triangle? Thank you in advance. This puzzle seems to be pretty interesting for me :)

Comment: @OlegIgnatov - As for me, it works correctly for any value of m >= 0.  Can you give an counterexample?

Comment: Sorry, I have just tryed it. It work. But do you agree that for m>=n the result can be calculated by the following formula: 2^(n-1)?